# Receive push notifications from APNS to Titanium (iOS) App without using Appcelerator Cloudpush (ACS)?

Tags: ios, titanium, apple-push-notifications

I'm now responsible for a initial release of an app for iOS and Android.  The developer that started the work has left the company and we are left with an incomplete Titanium application to finish.

Once this app is finished we do not plan to continue using Titanium.

We need to add push notifications to this app.

We have enabled Android push notifications using the standard GCM push servers using http://iamyellow.net/post/40100981563/gcm-appcelerator-titanium-module or https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5165#!overview

Does anyone know of a guide to use APNS that connects directly to the Apple servers and does not require sending the notification payload via ACS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get the device token from apple to do this you have to register for Push notifications, you will find it in detail [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications-section-37551717_Subscribingtopushnotifications-ObtainingadevicetokenoniOS)

The process that follows is saving the token to your database and using it to send Push notifications, this [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) explains it best.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great, I've not tested this yet, but I can see that we will get the push received callback function directly from the request to register with the APNS via the Ti.Network.registerForPushNotifications.