# Asking about remote notification using Titanium

Tags: notifications, titanium, tableview

i'm developping my first mobile app using itanium SDK version 3.2.3.GA, witch contains a list of person loaded from remote database (using php web services). I wan't to notifiy these persons from this list to accpet a meeting, and i do not know how can i do this using notification. I searched about remote notification and the ASC notification and i learned about email dialog on the documentation but i didn't have the response of my question. Realy i wan't to know witch is the best solution to notifiy a person using its email adress or what exactly should i do. Your help please... i spend much time asking and searching about this without result. Thanks. If there are some examples it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Push notifications, they are available for both Android and iOS for android you can find them under GCM for android and for iOS under APNS.

For ios you can check my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301077/receive-push-notifications-from-apns-to-titanium-ios-app-without-using-appcele/24303307#24303307) Answer.

for android you can Integrate GCM module from [appcelerator marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/home).

Hope it helps.