# Is there any way for sending push notifications without appcelaretor cloud services?

Tags: push-notification, titanium

I already know how to send push notifications in Titanium with Alloy, the way I do is:

```
        // Require the module
    var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
    var deviceToken = null;

    // Initialize the module
    CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
        success: deviceTokenSuccess,
        error: deviceTokenError
    });
    // Enable push notifications for this device
    // Save the device token for subsequent API calls
    function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
        deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
       // alert("--->" + deviceToken);
        subscribeToChannel();
    }
    function deviceTokenError(e) {
        alert('Failed to register for push notifications! ' + e.error);
    }

    // Process incoming push notifications
    CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
        alert("Notification received: " + evt.payload);
    });


    // For this example to work, you need to get the device token. See the previous section.
    // You also need an ACS user account.
    // Require in the Cloud module
    var Cloud = require("ti.cloud");

    function loginUser(){
     // Log in to ACS
        Cloud.Users.login({
            login: 'example',
            password: 'example'
        }, function (e) {
     if (e.success) {
                alert('Login successful');
            } else {
                alert('Error:\n' +
                    ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
        });
    }
    function subscribeToChannel(){
     // Subscribe the user and device to the 'test' channel
     // Specify the push type as either 'android' for Android or 'ios' for iOS
     // Check if logged in:
        Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
            channel: 'test',
            //device_token: 'APA91bHRjGoZLCYKwn-XcCtNLETuf-KRKfT4sMgVE4KgXQgInYfZuYTNrZC7FUMugLs0idzzqtLytrvVJjVzYBzQoc7Q81hEerq0O2vww_tV8mACuUfAi0JRvs7LoufnQZpYLZrb_1rlUsIOEMsPxDs9b_pIRJF5rw',
            device_token:deviceToken,
            type: Ti.Platform.name == 'android' ? 'android' : 'ios'
        }, function (e) {
     if (e.success) {
                alert('Subscribed');
            } else {
                alert('Error:\n' +
                    ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
        });
    }
    function unsubscribeToChannel (){
     // Unsubscribes the user and device from the 'test' channel
        Cloud.PushNotifications.unsubscribe({
            channel: 'test',
            device_token: deviceToken
        }, function (e) {
     if (e.success) {
                alert('Unsubscribed');
            } else {
                alert('Error:\n' +
                    ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
        });
    }



 loginUser();
```

However this way is only for sending push notification through https://cloud.appcelerator.com/ such a manually because it is needed you write the alert and push the button in that backend site.

So my question: Is there any way for sending push notification in Titanium from an own server in an "automatically" way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301077/receive-push-notifications-from-apns-to-titanium-ios-app-without-using-appcele/24303307#24303307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

How to obtain a device token for push notifications is described in the Titanium docs, [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Subscribing_to_push_notifications).

To send notifications you have to send the token to your server. The server then sends your notification to Apple Push Notification Services (APNS). See Apple docs. That's not "automatic" but it's a simple task for PHP or any other language - you can find a lot of scripts.

You can also schedule local notifications which might come in handy depending on your case.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I'm going to read the documentation more carefuly and then I'm going to search a simple task in PHP, I think that in PHP is easier configure this kind of services.